# Default template parameter syntax

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

my question may look strange for many of you and I am really sorry for that.

As I can remember, I managed few years ago to define a class with a default template parameter such that the syntax

```
Foo<> f;
```

can be replaced by

```
Foo f;
```

However, I cannot remember how I did that. I thought Foo class was defined with variadic templates and the default template parameter was an integer value (SIZE) but I don't manage to reproduce the target syntax.

Does anybody know how to do that?
If it was just a dream, I'm really sorry!

EDIT: well, as far as I can remember, the base of the trick was to redefine

```
template<int SIZE=0>
class Foo;
```

with some variadic templates. But I am aware that my question is strange and that it is probably impossible to obtain such a syntax... :)

Comment: The phrase `If it was just a dream....` just made my day :) (You are far from the only person on this site who dreams in code)

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of a function template?

Comment: Are you talking about syntax in the template definition or something? If so, it would help if you gave a small example of the template you are defining.

Comment: Nice comment Chris! :)

Comment: I am sure that my dream was dealing with a class and not a function! ^^

Comment: The syntax concerns the instanciation of the class but I can give an example of what I can remember about this dream.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as the great philosopher Nelly said, it was only just a dream.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like

```
template<size_t SIZE = 0>
struct Foo {
   // ...
};
```

See [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c8e3022089cc7f0)

---

Reducing that to

```
Foo f;
```

isn't possible though.

Comment: Sure, I know that! I feel I managed to find a trick to make it possible with variadic templates but I know it is suspicious... :)

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution would be to define an alias to you type.

```
template<std::size_t size = 0>
struct Foo {
   // ...
};

using DefaultFoo = Foo<>;
```

You can't have the same name though...